# How is this particular Rust code implemented?

Tags: rust

I'm reading [the documentation for the Amethyst game engine](https://book.amethyst.rs/book/stable/concepts/resource), and I've encountered this interesting piece of code:

```
use amethyst::ecs::World;

struct MyResource {
    pub game_score: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut world = World::empty();
    
    let my = MyResource {
        game_score: 0,
    };
    
    world.insert(my);
}
```

And:

```
  // try_fetch returns a Option<Fetch<MyResource>>
  let fetched = world.try_fetch::<MyResource>();
  if let Some(fetched_resource) = fetched {
      //dereference Fetch<MyResource> to access data
      assert_eq!(*fetched_resource, MyResource{ game_score: 0, });
  } else {
      println!("No MyResource present in `World`");
  }
```

And I don't see how it can work, really.

Apparently, there is some kind of collection inside World that can hold members of a completely arbitrary data type -- how can that be possible? The MyResource struct doesn't implement any particular trait, so we can't say something like Box<dyn Trait>.

And then we can recover that item based on its type. Again, I can't see how this can work. How can we iterate through a collection and check every item's type? Is there even a dynamic type checker in Rust? Again, the struct does not implement any particular trait, so how can it possibly interface with it at all?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Amethyst, but solely based on the code you provided, they could be using a macro to implement a trait for any type which needs to be stored, then collecting it as a dynamic trait object.

Comment: The documentation isn't building for the most recent version, but in an earlier version they had a blanket implementation for the `Resource` trait: https://docs.rs/amethyst/0.13.0/amethyst/prelude/struct.World.html#method.insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of [insert](https://docs.rs/amethyst/0.13.0/amethyst/prelude/struct.World.html#method.insert):

```
pub fn insert<R>(&mut self, r: R) where
    R: Resource,
```

There is a [blanket implementation](https://docs.rs/amethyst/0.13.0/amethyst/prelude/struct.World.html#impl-Resource) for Resource

```
impl<T> Resource for T where
    T: Any + Send + Sync,
```

There is also a blanket implementation for Any ([Any trait implementors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#implementors)):

```
impl<T> Any for T where
    T: 'static + ?Sized,
```

The [Any docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/index.html) are probably also relevant.

**Conclusion**: your MyResource does implement a relevant trait, namely the Resource trait.

Comment: The Any trait is exactly what I wanted. Thank you